# R: plotting actual vs observed with mixed effects model

Tags: r, effects, mixed

I have a data set:

```
 date=c(56,54,112,230,250,134,114)
 species=c("pink","blue","pink","green","black","orange","purple")
 year=c(1901,2000,1958,1978,1992,1992,1994)
 loc=c("forest","river","river","cloud","cloud")
 peop=c(1.0,-6.2,1.55,0.45,-2.8,3.45,4.1)
 per=c(1,5,63,9,45,1,2)
 tem=c(12,65,14,35,26,24,22)
 high=c(2500,3400,2600,2800,2546,2148,3654)
```

From this data set I created a mixed effects model:

```
 model<-lmer(date~(1|species)+ high + year + tem*peop + per)
```

I need a graph that plots the actual observed values for date vs the predicted ones by the model. Thanks!

Comment: You should improve your previous question instead of making a new one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612012/r-graphing-mixed-effects-model-against-observed-values

Answer (score 1):

Construct data (it's better to have data in a data frame rather than lying around in your global workspace):

```
dd <-
    data.frame(date=c(56,54,112,230,250,134,114),
               species=c("pink","blue","pink","green","black",
               "orange","purple"),
               year=c(1901,2000,1958,1978,1992,1992,1994),
               ## I added a couple of values here since the
               ##  length didn't match the other variables
               loc=c("forest","river","river","cloud","cloud","forest","forest"),
               peop=c(1.0,-6.2,1.55,0.45,-2.8,3.45,4.1),
               per=c(1,5,63,9,45,1,2),
               tem=c(12,65,14,35,26,24,22),
               high=c(2500,3400,2600,2800,2546,2148,3654))
```

This model can't actually be fit with a data set this short, so I replicated it (still very artificial, but OK for illustration)

```
dd <- do.call(rbind,replicate(10,dd,simplify=FALSE))

library("lme4")
model<-lmer(date~(1|species)+ high + year + tem*peop + per,dd)
```

Plot expected (x-axis) vs observed (y axis):

```
plot(fitted(model),dd$date)
abline(a=0,b=1)  ## 1-to-1 line
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!! I knew it was something very simple.

Comment: Sorry last question, is there a way to see the residual graph from that one?

Comment: oh, can you just obtain the R2 value for that graph easily?

Comment: Please read some things like http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq and http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/R/misc/foxchapter/bolker_chap.html rather than peppering new questions in the comments ...